# C++ GMP Generating Random Number

Tags: c++, random, biginteger, gmp

I'm trying to generate a huge random number in C++ using the GMP library but am having issues figuring out the syntax. This is slightly different from other examples I've found because I need to set a floor and ceiling for the random number to be between. This is kinda what I need to do:

```
mpz_class high, low;

low  = pow(2,199);
high = pow(2,210);

// code to use the high and low numbers to generate the random number
```

I know this isn't much to go on, but again, I'm not sure what the syntax would even be at this point, I've tried several things but nothing I've found enables me to tell GMP to use a high and low range for the number generation.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not adverse to switching libraries to something like TTMath, I just chose GMP because I've read good things about it.

Comment: So, basically, the code you show is irrelevant and you want to know if there is a method in gmp that allows for generation of random numbers in a specific range?

Comment: Ha, yes. thats it correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Gmp Lib Documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Random-Numbers.html#Integer-Random-Numbers)

> Function: void mpz_urandomb (mpz_t rop, gmp_randstate_t state,
>   mp_bitcnt_t n)
>
> Generate a uniformly distributed random integer in the range 0 to
>   2^n−1, inclusive

So, take 210 - 199, and use that as n, generate a random number and add the result to pow(2,199).

If you want something more granular than a power of 2 upper limit, this won't work for you.  You could try the unsigned int sized random function using the same technique above:

> — Function: unsigned long gmp_urandomm_ui (gmp_randstate_t state, unsigned long n)
>
> Return a uniformly distributed random number in the range 0 to n-1, inclusive.

Here, you would find your granular range and use that for n.  Then add the random number to your lower value.  The limitation is n must be less than MAXUINT, usually 2^32 -1

Comment: To generate a number between 0 and n, you can generate a number smaller than 2^k (which is larger than n) and if the number is larger than n then try again until it is small enough.

Comment: @MarcGlisse good point - but not knowing random number theory, the result just seems somewhat marred, besides it taking an indeterminate number of loops to get the result, still a +1

Comment: Alright, I got the numbers to be generated but it doesn't appear that I can perform basic math operations on a `mpz_t` type variable.  I get the following when adding the result back to `mpz_ui_pow_ui(high,2,199)`:  

`invalid operands to binary expression ('__mpz_struct *' and '__mpz_struct *')     frand = rand + low;`

Comment: @Les nothing like a wikipedia link to make a statement look more serious ;-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling

Comment: For C++, you probably want to look at this page instead: https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Random-Numbers.html

Answer (score 6):

Using the logic presented by @Less, I wrote the following to solve my problem:

```
void 
makeprime ()
{
    // *********************** VARIABLE DECLARATION *********************** //
    // initilize the variables as gmp class instances
    mpz_t l, rand;
    unsigned long seed;
    // perform inits to create variable pointers with 0 value
    mpz_inits(l, rand);
    //mpz_init(rand);

    // calculate the random number floor
    mpz_ui_pow_ui(l, 2, 199);

    // initilze the state object for the random generator functions
    gmp_randstate_t rstate;
    // initialize state for a Mersenne Twister algorithm. This algorithm is fast and has good randomness properties.
    gmp_randinit_mt(rstate);

    // create the generator seed for the random engine to reference 
    gmp_randseed_ui(rstate, seed);

    /*
    Function:
    int mpz_probab_prime_p (const mpz_t n, int reps)

    Determine whether n is prime. Return 2 if n is definitely prime, return 1 if n is probably prime (without being certain), 
    or return 0 if n is definitely composite.
    */
    do {
        // return a uniformly distributed random number in the range 0 to n-1, inclusive.
        mpz_urandomb(rand, rstate, 310);

        // add the random number to the low number, which will make sure the random number is between the low and high ranges
        mpz_add(rand, rand, l);

        gmp_printf("randomly generated number: %Zd\n", rand);

    } while ( !(mpz_probab_prime_p(rand, 25)) );        

    // *********************** GARBAGE COLLECTION *********************** //
    // empty the memory location for the random generator state
    gmp_randclear(rstate);
    // clear the memory locations for the variables used to avoid leaks
    mpz_clear(l);
    mpz_clear(rand);
}
```

Thanks @Less for your logic and help!

Comment: mpz_inits causing segmentation fault, try using mpz_init (no "s") and initialize l and rand separately.